# Получение слова с символом из строки php

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из строки:

```
'text @user texttexttext text @user2 texttext'
```

получить в массив?

```
@user
@user2
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/G5237k/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/@[^\h]+/', 'text @user texttexttext text @user2 texttext', $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

https://3v4l.org/BBf5D

Comment: то что нужно только как теперь реализовать чтобы в одном массиве было? http://i.imgur.com/5CvWcjk.png

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'text @user texttexttext text @user2 texttext';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/@user\d*/', $str, $matches);
```